# How do I set the number of characters output in a fprintf '%s' format using a variable?

Tags: c, file, printf

I need to write a variable number of characters to a file. For example, lets say I want to print 3 characters. "TO" would print "TO" to a file. "LongString of Characters" would print "Lon" to a file.

How can I do this? (the number of characters is defined in another variable). I know that this is possible fprintf(file,"%10s",string), but that 10 is predefined

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This one corresponds to your example:

```
fprintf(file, "%*s", 10, string);
```

but you mentioned a maximum as well, to also limit the number:

```
fprintf(file, "%*.*s", 10, 10, string);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need "%*s" and you'll need to pass the length as an integer before the string.

Comment: This will print _at least_ that many characters, and will not limit the number of characters printed.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, why not try this:

```
void print_limit(char *string, size_t num)
{
  char c = string[num];
  string[num] = 0;
  fputs(string, file);
  string[num] = c;
}
```

Temporarily truncates the string to the length you want and then restores it. Sure, it's not strictly necessary, but it works, and it's quite easy to understand.

Comment: If you do this... be sure that the length of `string` is at least `num-1` or you will be temporarily overwriting some random byte of memory!!

Comment: This is true. Let it be a lesson never to trust hastily/lazily written code you get off the internet.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you may create "c_str" from your buffer and prepare string to printf like I do that in this source:

```
void print(char *val, size_t size) {
    char *p = (char *)malloc(size+1); // +1 to zero char
    char current;
    for (int i=0; i < size; ++i) {
        current = val[i];
        if (current != '\0') {
           p[i] = current; 
        } else {
           p[i] = '.'; // keep in mind that \0 was replace by dot
        }
        p[i+1] = '\0';
    }
    printf("%s", p);
    free(p);
}
```

But it solution wrong way. You shuld use fprintf with format "%*s".